# Alternative Class Providers and Dependency Injection

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am trying to inject both the XRDService and the SESSION_SERVICE_TOKEN into my CartService, however, I am getting this error:

`Can't resolve all parameters for CartService: (?, [object Object]).`

What's the difference between a normal service and an alternative class provider when it comes to DI? [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#class-provider) explains a little bit, but I'm still confused.

I can inject the SESSION_SERVICE_TOKEN in services that are provided in lower modules, just not when they are provided in the same module. Why is that? Are there any workarounds?

app.module.ts:

```
providers: [
  { provide: SESSION_SERVICE_TOKEN, useClass: ClientSessionService },
  XRDService,
  CartService,
]
```

cart.service.ts:

```
constructor(@Inject(SESSION_SERVICE_TOKEN) sessionService: SessionService, 
  private xrdService: XRDService) {}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a circular dependency problem. I was injecting the cartService into ClientSessionService while also trying to inject the ClientSessionService into the cartService. I removed the cart dependency from the ClientSessionService and all is well.